# How to Iterate through LinkedList that contains Object - Java

Tags: java, arrays, tostring

How can i iterate through my LinkedList which i added Objects?

```
private LinkedList sensors = new LinkedList();
enter code here

//Constructor for my class is taking three arguments
public Sensor(int ID, String Name, String comments) {
    this.ID = ID;
    this.NAME = Name;       
    this.COMMENTS = comments;
}

//Then I query the database to get the values of the variables to create a new Object
ID = Integer.parseInt(dbResult.getString("sensorID") );
        NAME = dbResult.getString("sensorName");    
        COMMENTS = dbResult.getString("sensorcomments");

        //create a new sensor object
        Sensor newSensor = new Sensor(ID, NAME, COMMENTS);

        //add the sensor to the list
        addSensor(newSensor);
```

`
The problem that i am having is that i can add the Sensor Object to the Linked List but when I try to loop through it i get a reference as a result instead of the object or its values.

```
//display the results of the Linked List
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sensors.toArray()));
```

the output that I get is
[Sensor@4d405ef7, Sensor@6193b845, Sensor@2e817b38, Sensor@c4437c4, Sensor@433c675d, Sensor@3f91beef]

Thank you

Comment: What are you expecting the outcome of `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sensors.toArray()));` to be?

Comment: Implement toString() for Sensor. You will be fine.

Comment: I was looking to get the option to retrieve the variables to a especific object on the LinkedList. Eg LinkedList.get(1).getID Or LinkedList.get(1).getName   Or LinkedList.get(1).getComments

Comment: @WilFerraciolli, assuming getId, getName and getComments methods are public,it should work. Just keep in mind that LinkedList is not the best data structure to access elements by index. You might want to consider `ArrayList` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method in your `Sensor` class.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "id: "+ID+"; name: "+NAME+"; comments: "+ COMMENTS;
}
```

[`Arrays.toString(Object[] a)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object[]%29) will call each of your `Sensor` object's `toString()` method.

Here's a more complete example of a `Sensor` class with recommended variable name changes:

```
class Sensor {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String comments;

    public Sensor(int id, String name, String comments) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;       
        this.comments = comments;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        //You can change how to the string is built in order to achieve your desired output.
        return "id: "+ID+"; name: "+name+"; comments: "+ comment;
    }

}
```

Comment: This worked, it return an array of all of them split into commas which helped me. thank you

Comment: @WilFerraciolli I'm glad I could help.  If you feel this solves your problem, please accept the answer and/or upvote.